# Calculate the expected value of the highest floor the elevator may reach.

Tags: probability

I've been to solve this exercise for a few hours now, and all the methods I use seems wrong, I'll be glad if someone could solve this for me, since I don't know how to approach this correctly.

Given a building with 11 floors while the bottom floor is the ground floor (floor 0), and the rest of the floors are numbered from $1-10$, $12$ people gets into an elevator in the ground floor, and choose randomly and in independent way the floor they wish to go (which one of them has the probablility of $\frac{1}{10}$ to choose any floor in independent matter of the others).

Calculate the expected value of the highest floor the elevator may reach?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this problem is same as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214713/expected-value-problem-10-floors-and-12-people-get-on-an-elevator?rq=1

Comment: The last line is a command, not a question, so the question mark at the end of it seems inappropriate. And in any case, this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, so please describe the effort that you've made in attempting to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: @Steve Yang It not the same question very simliar yet different question about the same topic.

Comment: @barak manos I'm well aware of that, Usually I do post what I manage to do (you could see my previous questions) but in this exercise I don't find a way to approach this problem, about the last line, English is not a native language (I speak 2 other languages beside English), I apologize if it came out as command instand of a question I didn't meant that.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry if my comment has offended you. At first glance the question seemed rather effortless, but I see that you're a "good user" in general. +1, and I'll see if I can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the highest floor that the elevator reaches, then:

- $P(X=1)=\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{12}$
- $P(X=n)=\left(\frac{n}{10}\right)^{12}-P(X=n-1)$

Hence:

$E(X)=$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}n\cdot P(X=n)=$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}n\cdot\left(\left(\frac{n}{10}\right)^{12}-\left(\frac{n-1}{10}\right)^{12}\right)=$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}n\cdot\left(\frac{n^{12}-(n-1)^{12}}{10^{12}}\right)=$

$9.632571463867$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $X_i$ is the floor that the $i$-th person chooses, you need to calculate the expectation of $X =\max \limits_{i=1}^{12}X_i$. Start by calculating $P(X \le k)$.

Answer (score 0):

The highest floor that the elevator reaches is the maximum $M$ of the floors chosen by the 12 people.

For $m = 1,\dots,10$, the probability that $M \leq m$ is just the probability that all 12 people chose floors less than or  equal to $m$, $$\left(\frac {m}{10}\right)^{12}$$
So the probability that $M=m$ is $$\left(\frac {m}{10}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac {m-1}{10}\right)^{12}  = \frac{m^{12}-(m-1)^{12}} {10^{12}}$$
Hence the expected value of $M$ is $$\sum_{m=1}^{10} m \ \frac{m^{12}-(m-1)^{12}} {10^{12}} = \frac{1}{10^{12}}\left(\sum m^{13} - \sum (m-1)^{13} -\sum 
(m-1)^{12} \right) 
 $$
By cancellation, this equals
$$\frac{1}{10^{12}}\left(10^{13} - (1^{12} + \dots + 9^{12}) \right) 
 $$
Putting this into a computer gives the answer. It can be approximated by noting that $\frac{7^{12}}{10^{12}} \approx 0.014$ is small, so throwing away terms smaller than this gives $$10-\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^{12} \approx 9.6$$

Comment: How did you arrive at $\sum_{m=1}^{10} m \ \frac{m^{12}-(m-1)^{12}} {10^{12}} = \frac{1}{10^{12}}\left(\sum m^{13} - \sum (m-1)^{13} -\sum 
m^{12} \right)$?

Comment: Using $m \times (m-1)^{12} = (m-1) \times (m-1)^{12} + 1 \times (m-1)^{12} = (m-1)^{13} + (m-1)^{12} $

Comment: Well, that's not what I see on the right-hand side of the expression.

Comment: I think that you should change the right-most term from $\sum m^{12}$ to $\sum (m-1)^{12}$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right! Thanks, I have edited.